Updating a column based on the conditions within a resultset
I have a requirement to update HNI Flag (High Networth Individual) flag on a particular policy.
There are many conditions which determine whether the individual is a HNI or not.
Contact(CONTACT) table will contain the policy holder information. Contact table has ROW_ID, INTEGRATION_ID, CUSTOMER_TYPE, HNI_FLG and many other fields. INTEGRATION_ID is like ROW_ID which is unique for each contact.
Policy (ASSET) table will contain the policy information. Policy table has ROW_ID, POLICY_NUM, HNI_FLAG and many other fields.
CONTACT table and ASSET table are linked via an inter table (AST_CON) and it contains various roles that are present for policy like Owner, Life Assured, Payor, Beneficiary etc. There is also one more table called CAMPAIGN table which determines the campaign during which the contact purchased the policy. Below are the conditions which determine the HNI flag.

If the HNI flag at campaign level(CAMP_CODE) or contact level(CUSTOMER_TYPE) is HNI, then policy level HNI flag is Y only when the contact role(RELATION_TYPE) is Owner. This Owner can have multiple policies and other roles in different policies. So, we will also need to update the HNI flag to Y on those policies as well.
If the HNI flag at campaign level(CAMP_CODE) or contact level(CUSTOMER_TYPE) is another other value apart from HNI (NULL included), then policy level HNI flag is N only when the contact role(RELATION_TYPE)  is Owner. This Owner can have multiple policies and other roles in different policies. So, we will also need to update the HNI flag to N on those policies as well.

Here is the relationship.
SELECT CON.INTEGRATION_ID, 
CON.CUSTOMER_TYPE, 
POL.HNI_FLAG,
POL.POLICY_NUM, 
PLOX.RELATION_TYPE, 
CAMP.CAMP_CODE
FROM CONTACT CON, 
ASSET POL, 
ASSET_CON PLOX, 
CAMPAIGN CAMP 
WHERE CON.ROW_ID = PLOX.CONTACT_ID 
AND POL.ROW_ID = PLOX.ASSET_ID 
AND POL.ROW_ID = CAMP.PAR_ROW_ID 


Currently, the data is like this



INTEGRATION_ID
CUSTOMER_TYPE
HNI_FLAG
POLICY_NUM
RELATION_TYPE
CAMP_CODE




51178
OTH
N
137456
Owner
NULL


51178
OTH
N
132345
Owner
NULL


51178
NULL
N
132235
Payor
NULL


51178
OTH
Y
132323
Life Assured
NULL


51178
OTH
N
132345
Life Assured
IND


55346
OTH
Y
158954
Payor
HNI


55346
NULL
N
158954
Life Assured
VEST


55346
NULL
N
158954
Owner
VEST


55346
NULL
Y
152354
Owner
VEST


55346
NULL
Y
122354
Owner
HNI


N3014
OTH
N
114555
Owner
HNI


N3014
HNI
Y
002133
Beneficiary
HNI


N3014
HNI
N
422133
Payor
NULL



Now we want to see below.

All the policies related to INTEGRATION_ID - 51178 HNI_FLAG should be N
All the policies related to INTEGRATION_ID - 55346 HNI_FLAG should be Y
All the policies related to INTEGRATION_ID - N3014 HNI_FLAG should be N

I wrote this query, but it is updating the data correctly and in some instances, I am getting single-row subquery returns more than one row.
UPDATE ASSET POL
SET POL.HNI_FLAG = (
    SELECT MAX(OWN_POL.HNI_FLAG)
    FROM AST_CON PLOX
    JOIN ASSET OWN_POL ON OWN_POL.ROW_ID = PLOX.ASSET_ID
    WHERE PLOX.CONTACT_ID = (SELECT CONTACT_ID FROM AST_CON WHERE ASSET_ID = POL.ROW_ID)
    AND PLOX.RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner'
)
WHERE POL.ROW_ID IN (
    SELECT PLOX.ASSET_ID
    FROM AST_CON PLOX
    WHERE PLOX.CONTACT_ID IN (
        SELECT PLOX.CONTACT_ID
        FROM AST_CON PLOX
        WHERE PLOX.RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner'
    )
);


MERGE INTO ASSET AST
USING
(
SELECT DISTINCT AST1.ROW_ID AS RID,
    MAX(HNI_FLAG) OVER (PARTITION BY CON.ROW_ID) AS MAX_HNI_FLAG,
    CON.CUSTOMER_TYPE
FROM ASSET AST1,
CONTACT CON,
AST_CON ASTCON
WHERE AST1.ROW = ASTCON.ASSET_ID
AND CON.ROW_ID = ASTON.CONTACT_ID
AND CON.CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'NRI'
AND ASTCON.RELATION_TYPE IN ('Owner')
) SRC
ON (SRC.RID = AST.ROWID AND (SRC.MAX_HNI_FLAG = 'Y' OR SRC.CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'HNI'))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET HNI_FLAG = 'Y'
WHERE HNI_FLAG IS NULL OR HNI_FLAG != 'Y';

I need to update the values in HNI_FLAG column with the conditions within the resultset.

what is the error?

"it is giving me error" isn't very helpful. What error? What investigation and debugging have you done? I'm also unclear how the subquery in your update relates to what you said earlier. If the earlier query is already correct, have you considered doing a merge instead of an update? Also your sample data is formatted badly, and you're joining multiple tables (with old syntax) which may not be relevant to your actual problem. It would be helpful if you could provide a full [mre].

@Andrew While updating one integration_id with two policies, it is updating correctly and in some instances where I am working on more than 3 integration_ids , I am getting single-row subquery returns more than one row.

@AlexPoole While updating one integration_id with two policies, it is updating correctly and in some instances where I am working on more than 3 integration_ids , I am getting single-row subquery returns more than one row. Yes, I used merge option as well. I am updating it in my question

In that case, you'll need to break down all those subqueries to find which is returning multiple rows.

Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data in the ASSET, CONTACT and AST_CON tables so that we can recreate the problem.

Your update command error, most probably, is caused by
...
WHERE PLOX.CONTACT_ID = (SELECT CONTACT_ID FROM AST_CON WHERE ASSET_ID = POL.ROW_ID)
...

... that is the only subquery that is supposed to fetch just one value.
But, if I got it right you are very close to the solution with your query showing us your current data.
Assuming that ROW_ID column in your ASSET table is unique - you could add that column to your question's first query. Additionaly you could also have a column that will fetch Max(HNI_FLAG) OVER() from rows with RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner' partitioned by INTEGRATION_ID:
SELECT    POL.ROW_ID "ASSET_ROW_ID",   -- add this line 
          CON.INTEGRATION_ID, CON.CUSTOMER_TYPE, 
          POL.HNI_FLAG, POL.POLICY_NUM, PLOX.RELATION_TYPE, CAMP.CAMP_CODE, 
          -- add the line below too
          Max(Case When PLOX.RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner' Then POL.HNI_FLAG End) "MAX_OWNER_HNI_FLAG"
FROM      CONTACT CON, ASSET POL, ASSET_CON PLOX, CAMPAIGN CAMP 
WHERE     CON.ROW_ID = PLOX.CONTACT_ID 
      AND POL.ROW_ID = PLOX.ASSET_ID 
      AND POL.ROW_ID = CAMP.PAR_ROW_ID 
/* NOTE: 
   please don't use tables list in FROM clause with WHERE conditions
   use JOIN ON syntax instead    */

... you should get something like this:
WITH  
  current_data ( ASSET_ROW_ID, INTEGRATION_ID, CUSTOMER_TYPE, HNI_FLAG, POLICY_NUM, RELATION_TYPE, CAMP_CODE ) AS
    ( Select 10105,  '51178',   'OTH',  'N',    137456, 'Owner',         NULL From Dual Union All 
      Select 10116,  '51178',   'OTH',  'N',    132345, 'Owner',         NULL   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11032,  '51178',    NULL,  'N',    132235, 'Payor',         NULL   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11075,  '51178',   'OTH',  'Y',    132323, 'Life Assured',  NULL   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11213,  '51178',   'OTH',  'N',    132345, 'Life Assured', 'IND'   From Dual Union All 
      --
      Select 11224,  '55346',   'OTH',  'Y',    158954, 'Payor',        'HNI'   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11242,  '55346',    NULL,  'N',    158954, 'Life Assured', 'VEST'  From Dual Union All 
      Select 11249,  '55346',    NULL,  'N',    158954, 'Owner',        'VEST'  From Dual Union All 
      Select 11289,  '55346',    NULL,  'Y',    152354, 'Owner',        'VEST'  From Dual Union All 
      Select 11300,  '55346',    NULL,  'Y',    122354, 'Owner',        'HNI'   From Dual Union All 
      --
      Select 11321,  'N3014',   'OTH',  'N',    114555, 'Owner',        'HNI'   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11356,  'N3014',   'HNI',  'Y',    002133, 'Beneficiary',  'HNI'   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11378,  'N3014',   'HNI',  'N',    422133, 'Payor',         NULL   From Dual
    )
Select     cd.*, Max(Case When RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner' Then HNI_FLAG End) 
                    Over(Partition By INTEGRATION_ID) as max_owner_hni_flag
From       current_data cd

/*      R e s u l t : 
ASSET_ROW_ID  INTEGRATION_ID  CUSTOMER_TYPE   HNI_FLAG  POLICY_NUM  RELATION_TYPE     CAMP_CODE  MAX_OWNER_HNI_FLAG
------------  --------------  --------------  --------  ----------  ----------------  ---------  ------------------
       10105  51178           OTH             N             137456  Owner             null       N
       10116  51178           OTH             N             132345  Owner             null       N
       11032  51178           null            N             132235  Payor             null       N
       11075  51178           OTH             Y             132323  Life Assured      null       N
       11213  51178           OTH             N             132345  Life Assured      IND        N
       11224  55346           OTH             Y             158954  Payor             HNI        Y
       11242  55346           null            N             158954  Life Assured      VEST       Y
       11300  55346           null            Y             122354  Owner             HNI        Y
       11289  55346           null            Y             152354  Owner             VEST       Y
       11249  55346           null            N             158954  Owner             VEST       Y
       11321  N3014           OTH             N             114555  Owner             HNI        N
       11356  N3014           HNI             Y               2133  Beneficiary       HNI        N
       11378  N3014           HNI             N             422133  Payor             null       N                    */

... and such a resultset could be used to update your ASSET table:
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :      ( ASSET table before update )
Create Table ASSET AS
  Select 10105 "ROW_ID", 137456 "POLICY_NUM", 'N' "HNI_FLAG" From Dual Union All
  Select 10116, 132345, 'N' From Dual Union All
  Select 11032, 132235, 'N' From Dual Union All
  Select 11075, 132323, 'Y' From Dual Union All
  Select 11213, 132345, 'N' From Dual Union All
  --
  Select 11224, 158954, 'Y' From Dual Union All
  Select 11242, 158954, 'N' From Dual Union All
  Select 11249, 158954, 'N' From Dual Union All
  Select 11289, 152354, 'Y' From Dual Union All
  Select 11300, 122354, 'Y' From Dual Union All
  --
  Select 11321, 114555, 'N' From Dual Union All
  Select 11356,   2133, 'Y' From Dual Union All
  Select 11378, 422133, 'N' From Dual;

... Update ASSET table - MERGE INTO ...
MERGE INTO ASSET a 
USING
(WITH  
  current_data ( ASSET_ROW_ID, INTEGRATION_ID, CUSTOMER_TYPE, HNI_FLAG, POLICY_NUM, RELATION_TYPE, CAMP_CODE ) AS
    ( Select 10105,  '51178',   'OTH',  'N',    137456, 'Owner',         NULL From Dual Union All 
      Select 10116,  '51178',   'OTH',  'N',    132345, 'Owner',         NULL   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11032,  '51178',    NULL,  'N',    132235, 'Payor',         NULL   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11075,  '51178',   'OTH',  'Y',    132323, 'Life Assured',  NULL   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11213,  '51178',   'OTH',  'N',    132345, 'Life Assured', 'IND'   From Dual Union All 
      --
      Select 11224,  '55346',   'OTH',  'Y',    158954, 'Payor',        'HNI'   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11242,  '55346',    NULL,  'N',    158954, 'Life Assured', 'VEST'  From Dual Union All 
      Select 11249,  '55346',    NULL,  'N',    158954, 'Owner',        'VEST'  From Dual Union All 
      Select 11289,  '55346',    NULL,  'Y',    152354, 'Owner',        'VEST'  From Dual Union All 
      Select 11300,  '55346',    NULL,  'Y',    122354, 'Owner',        'HNI'   From Dual Union All 
      --
      Select 11321,  'N3014',   'OTH',  'N',    114555, 'Owner',        'HNI'   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11356,  'N3014',   'HNI',  'Y',    002133, 'Beneficiary',  'HNI'   From Dual Union All 
      Select 11378,  'N3014',   'HNI',  'N',    422133, 'Payor',         NULL   From Dual
    )
Select     cd.*, Max(Case When RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner' Then HNI_FLAG End) 
                    Over(Partition By INTEGRATION_ID) as max_owner_hni_flag
From       current_data cd
) x ON(x.ASSET_ROW_ID = a.ROW_ID And x.max_owner_hni_flagIs Not Null)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET a.HNI_FLAG = x.max_owner_hni_flag
Where a.HNI_FLAG != x.max_owner_hni_flag;

4 rows affected

... check the data
Select * From ASSET Order By ROW_ID;

/*  S a m p l e    D a t a :      ( ASSET table after update )
ROW_ID  POLICY_NUM  HNI_FLAG
------  ----------  --------
 10105  137456      N
 10116  132345      N
 11032  132235      N
 11075  132323      N
 11213  132345      N
 11224  158954      Y
 11242  158954      Y
 11249  158954      Y
 11289  152354      Y
 11300  122354      Y
 11321  114555      N
 11356    2133      N
 11378  422133      N      */

See the fiddle here.
Using your code with two columns added - you could try to do the update like here:
MERGE INTO ASSET a 
USING 
(
SELECT    POL.ROW_ID "ASSET_ROW_ID",   
          CON.INTEGRATION_ID, CON.CUSTOMER_TYPE, 
          POL.HNI_FLAG, POL.POLICY_NUM, PLOX.RELATION_TYPE, CAMP.CAMP_CODE, 
          Max(Case When PLOX.RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner' Then POL.HNI_FLAG End) "MAX_OWNER_HNI_FLAG"
FROM      CONTACT CON, ASSET POL, ASSET_CON PLOX, CAMPAIGN CAMP 
WHERE     CON.ROW_ID = PLOX.CONTACT_ID 
      AND POL.ROW_ID = PLOX.ASSET_ID 
      AND POL.ROW_ID = CAMP.PAR_ROW_ID 
) x ON(x.ASSET_ROW_ID = a.ROW_ID And x.MAX_OWNER_HNI_FLAG Is Not Null)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET a.HNI_FLAG = x.MAX_OWNER_HNI_FLAG
Where a.HNI_FLAG != x.MAX_OWNER_HNI_FLAG;

